# Are the 4 triangles formed by midpoints of of a triangle congruent?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I recently purchased Paul Lockhart's math book titled "Measurement". In this book he asks math questions but avoids giving answers in order to motivate the reader to try the question themselves. I am a highschool freshman and inexperienced mathematician. Please don't judge.

This was a question that I attempted:

If the midpoints of **ANY** triangles sides are connected, this will make four different triangles. Are these four triangles congruent? Prove why or why not.

**Proof**

A(tri)/4 = bh/8       * let's assume that the triangles are congruent

A(par) = 2(tri)       * since **ANY** two congruent triangles can make a parallelogram

A(par)/8 = bh/8

A(tri)/4 = A(par)/8

8(1/2bh) = 4bh

4bh = 4bh

1 = 1

Comment: It feels a bit weird to me that you've assumed what you're trying to prove, I'm not sure if you're allowed to do that?

Comment: Doesn't this have a name? I think it's like the Triangle Midpoint Theorem...

Comment: @ $\sqrt{-1}$ There is one triangle only!

Comment: Note that there are 3 parallelogram in the figure . Also note that the the diagonal( which in this case will be the line joining the midpoints)of a parallelogram divides it into 2 congruent triangles. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Equal areas do not imply congruence .

Comment: @Avi I hate to admit it but you're absolutely right. All that work for nothing. Oh well...

Comment: No.  Learn this **!!NOW!!**.  If you start with assuming what you want to prove, and precede to showing there is no contradiction it means f#£¥ -all and proves *nothing*.  Here is proof that that 25 = 49.  Pf: assume 25 = 49 25-16=49-16.  9=(7+4)(7-4). 3x3=11x3.  3=11. 3-7 = 11 -7.  -4=4.  |-4|=|4|.  4=4.  Done.  Notice:  that is utter bollocks and means sod-all.  Your proof was doomed from the start.

Comment: Compare the sides of the triangles.  Each are exactly have of the corresponding side of the big triangle.  Such each triangle is congruent to each other by side-side-side.

Comment: @fleablood I was thinking that about assuming a possible false premise but wasn't sure. You could whittle down your example to "if $0=1$ then $0\times0=1\times0$ and since $0=0$ then $0=1$".

Comment: A proof by contradiction.  Assume false, conclude a contradiction=> therefore must be true-- is valid.  Direct proof:  state known true statements, conclude result must follow --- is valid.  A proof by confirmation-- show an example that result is possible and occurs-- not at all valid.  Proof by lack of contradiction (what you did):  assume true,  show one string of reasoning doesn't lead to contradiction--- utter BS and of no worth whatsoever, not even to confirm its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd argue it. Consider the triangle below, where $D$, $E$ and $F$ are midpoints. We can say that $EF$ and $AB$ are parallel and by extension, each interior edge between two midpoints is parallel to the exterior edge with the third midpoint. So then the triangle can be split into the four parallelograms $AFED$, $DFCE$ and $DFEB$. So then each pair of the $3$ triangles, except the middle one, share $2$ edges on opposite sides of a parallelogram and their third edge on an edge of $ABC$. For example, for $FEC$ and $ADF$, the edges $FE$ and $AD$ are opposite each other on a parallelogram and so are the edges $DF$ and $EC$. Since $AF=FC$, $AFD\cong FCE$. The inside triangle has all its edges on opposite sides of a parallelogram so all $4$ small triangles must be congruent.

[image: triangles]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Thale's theorem to show they have the same side lengths?

Comment: I guess that you could... However, at this point I'm just curious whether my proof makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved easily by using mid point theorem.  If $D$ and $E$ are mid points of sides $AB$ and $AC$ respectively, $DE$ is parallel to side $BC$ and Half in length to $BC$.  Also, $\angle D = \angle B$ and $\angle E = \angle C$, therefore, $\Delta ADE$ and $\Delta ABC$ are similar.  We know that if two similar triangles sides are in ratio $a : b$ then the ratio of their areas = ${a^2}:{b^2}$.  So their areas in the ratio ${1^2}:{2^2} = 1:4$

[image]

Similarly we can prove that $\Delta BDF$ and $\Delta ABC$ = ${1^2}:{2^2} = 1:4$

Also, $\Delta CEF$ and $\Delta ABC$ = ${1^2}:{2^2} = 1:4$

So it is clear that, $\Delta ADE = \Delta BDF = \Delta CEF = 1$

Therefore, $\Delta DEF$ = $ 4 - 3 = 1$

Comment: As one of the comments above says, equal areas doesn't imply congruence.